# PHP Mysql database class error

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop

I don't know why I am having this error. I'm using WampServer.
I am trying to configure my database thru OOP and I came up with this error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?>', expecting function
>   (T_FUNCTION)

```
 <?php
    Class Database{
        private $_host = null;
        private $_user = null;
        private $_pass = null;
        private $_db = null;
        var $con = false;

    public function connects($host, $user, $pass, $db){
        $this->_host = $host;
        $this->_user = $user;
        $this->_pass = $pass;
        $this->_db = $db;

        $this->con = mysql_connect($this->_host, $this->_user, $this->_pass);
        if(!$this->con){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            $sql = mysql_select_db($this->_db);
            if(!$sql){
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    } 
?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about playing "spot the missing bracket" game.


Comment: Dont'use mysql.it was deprecated.use PDO or mysqli

Comment: Close a bracket before ?>

Comment: oh shit! sorry for the lame question.. was very nice of you for noticing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing

```
}
```

to finalize the `class Database {`

To avoid this,
use proper line indention and follow the [Zend Coding Style Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/coding-standard.coding-style.html)